# iphone reset tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, reset

I'm having navigation controller with few views.
I've table view in one of the views. I'm showing tick mark when user selects a cell in table view. Upto this point, its fine.
When user goes back to previous view and comes back, i want to reset the table view. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to reload data, you can call [`[tableView reloadData]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW19).